# Unable to commit to github repo using egit

Tags: git, github, egit, eclipse-indigo

When I try to to commit ti github repo using egit I receive below error :

[image]

What does this error mean ? This is my first commit.

Here is how I am trying to commit :

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are the details of that exception? Can you click on the detail button and copy-paste it in this question? (no screen capture, copy-pate the text)

Comment: Details are the same as reason error : "Exception caught during execution of ls-remote command
Exception caught during execution of ls-remote command"

Comment: ok, so no call stack then. Can you clone that git repo through Egit? In other workds, are your network settings correctly set to allow https communication between your workstation and GitHub?

Comment: Egit does not give me the option to clone the repo. How can I check that my network settings are correctly setup ?

Comment: you can follow. Vogella's tutorial on Egit: if you can clone a Github report,  your setup (including network) are good. http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/article.html#github

Comment: @VonC, This is working now. I re-installed Egit and everything seems ok now. Thanks foe help. Answer for was to re-install Egit, perhaps incorrect version of Egit was installed for Indigo initially.

Comment: @VonC your comment "ok, so no call stack then. Can you clone that git repo through Egit? In other workds, are your network settings correctly set to allow https communication between your workstation and GitHub?" pointed me in right direction

Comment: Excellent. Don't forget to post an answer describing precisely what you did to solve the situation and what was the root cause of the issue, for other to benefit from your experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue for me was an incorrect version of egit. When using the eclipse update site I used the recommended version instead of the Indigo version.

From the [Egit download](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/download/) page:

[image]

Comment: Does not help me. It was also the exact same version. I need to uninstalled it first.

Answer (score 2):

On March 4, GitHub temporary disabled all the public keys until you approve them due to security reasons. I had the same problem when I tried to commit. For those who have met the same exceptions after March 4, 2012, go to https://github.com/settings/ssh/audit/ and approve your public keys so that you can pull-from/push-to your repository again.

Comment: True. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766682/how-can-i-review-my-ssh-key-for-github/9766805#9766805

Comment: Thanks for this. Knew it would be something simple! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Adding .git to the repository url worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would first ensure that your settings are correct by using [git bash](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) to clone the repository. This will print out any problems if you encounter an error. This will verify that your network settings and git settings are correct.

If you need a read-only URL, you could try using the github read-only URL, which looks like: `git://github.com/path/to/repo.git`

However, github users read/write URLs for pushing code to github. These URLs use the following format: `git@github.com:path/to/repo.git`. You can find these URL's listed on the github repo page. It may be that the problem you're encountering is if you're pushing to github but using the HTTP protocol rather than the read/write protocol `git@`.

Comment: Thank you but I'm trying to commit using Egit alone and trying to stay away from using git commands as much as I can.

Comment: @user470184 I know that, but since you're running into errors, you have to follow some procedures to debug the reason why Egit is failing. Besides, who needs GUI's anyway? -- The URL's that I gave you would still be used by Egit (theoretically). But if stuff isn't working, you need to figure out why, sometimes that means getting into the terminal isn't such a bad thing and will save you a ton of headache.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the ssh key setup on github was not done correctly. As soon as I removed repository specific deploy keys and defined a global ssh key things started to work as expected for me

Answer (score -1):

Going to the right depth in the repository url to match which directory .git is actually in (without specifying .git itself) worked for me.  I was trying to go one level too high.