# How can I review my SSH key for github?

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

I recently got an e-mail from Github saying that I should review my SSH key:

> Please review your keys and ensure you
>   recognize them. If you have any doubts whatsoever, reject the keys and
>   upload new keys.

How do I review my keys with git on ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can follow the GitHub guide "[Reviewing your SSH keys](https://help.github.com/en/articles/reviewing-your-ssh-keys)"

> To verify your SSH keys you need to find the fingerprint of each key on your computer and compare it to the fingerprint displayed on GitHub.
>
> What’s a Fingerprint?

An SSH key’s fingerprint is a sequence of bytes unique to that key.
Fingerprints are usually encoded into hexadecimal strings and formatted into groups of characters for readability.

> We display SSH key fingerprints on GitHub along with the key’s title:

[image: key fingerprint]

From there, for Ubuntu, you can refer to "[How do I find my RSA key fingerprint on ubuntu 10.04 (hosted by linode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607295/how-do-i-find-my-rsa-key-fingerprint-on-ubuntu-10-04-hosted-by-linode)" (-l here means to "list" instead of create).

```
$ ssh-keygen -E md5 -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: That GitHub guide is gone. Most similar content appears to be https://help.github.com/en/articles/reviewing-your-ssh-keys

Comment: @jamieguinan Thank you. I have revised the answer accordingly.

Comment: What do you think about adding `-E md5` to the example command? Github shows fingerprints in md5 format, but newer `ssh-keygen` now defaults to sha256.

Comment: @jamieguinan Actually... I would add also -m PEM when generating a new key: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309! I will edit the answer per your recommendation in the case of listing the fingerprint.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use [https://github.com/username.keys](https://github.com/chx.keys) (I used my keys as a demo URL).

Answer (score 5):

If you have a bunch of keys to compare with the GitHub fingerprint this line comes in handy:

```
cd ~/.ssh; for k in *.pub; do ssh-keygen -E md5 -lf $k; done
```

Comment: Beauty! It was the -E md5 part that I was missing to verify my key on github.

Answer (score 2):

Try to push / pull to one of your own repositories on github.
A message will appear that the current key is not authorized.
In addition is the SSH fingerprint of the current computer and a link displayed where 
it is possible to review your keys.
Follow the link and mark the SSH key from your computer as approved.